# Subset a dataframe by time

Tags: r

I am working on a dataframe which I have previously intergrated the time and date into one column (called timestamp):

```
a <-c(1:21)
D <- c("2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14", "2012/12/14")
Time <- c("18:40:37", "18:40:48", "18:40:58", "18:41:08","18:41:18","18:41:28","18:41:38","18:41:48","18:41:58","18:42:08","18:42:18","18:42:28","18:42:38","18:42:48","18:42:58","18:43:08","18:43:18","18:42:28", "18:44:18", "18:44:28", "18:44:28")
df1 <- data.frame(a, D, Time)
df1 <- within(df1, { timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(D, Time)), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })
```

How would I subset the dataframe to exclude values after a specific point in time?  I found some code in Stackoverflow for a similar question that I thought might be able to help, but I am struggling to get the time element to work:

```
subset(df1, format.Date(timestamp, ""%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"") >"14/12/2012 18:42:00")
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Edit:
I am struggling to get the code detailed below working on my real data. A dput() of the first four rows of my dataframe are listed at the end of this post.  I previously used the line of code recommended by @Arun to timestamp my data.

```
gps <- within(gps, { timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(LOCAL.DATE, LOCAL.TIME)), 
+                                       "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })
```

If I try and apply the second part of the code (strptime...) I get the error message:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "timestamp", value = list(sec = c(37,  : 
  replacement has 30208 rows, data has 4
This sort of explains when I try and appy the code to the whole of my data I get 8 rows of many numbers, separated by a comma.  If you can help me in any way, I would be extremely grateful.

```
structure(list(timestamp = c("14/12/2012 18:40:37", "14/12/2012 18:40:48", 
"14/12/2012 18:40:58", "14/12/2012 18:41:08"), LATITUDE = c(54.77769505, 
54.77765729, 54.77768751, 54.7777021), LONGITUDE = c(-1.56627049, 
-1.56639255, -1.56626555, -1.56662523), HEIGHT = c(" 173.911 M", 
" 161.742 M", " 146.905 M", " 138.016 M"), SPEED = c(" 0.465 km/h", 
" 0.728 km/h", " 4.574 km/h", " 17.335 km/h")), .Names = c("timestamp", 
"LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "HEIGHT", "SPEED"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Second edit:** Many thanks @Arun for the solution.  I was a bit confused how I was suppose to use the code as my data is originally in date and time columns (LOCAL.DATE and LOCAL.TIME).  So I used the first line of code from your orginal solution, and then the second line from your revised edits.

This is the code I used:

```
gps <- within(gps, { timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(LOCAL.DATE, LOCAL.TIME)), 
                                      "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })

gps$timestamp <- strptime(gps$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

However now I get a string of NAs (and some -1s).  Apologies if I used the code in the incorrect way...

**Third edit**
Apologies for the confusion @Arun.  When I try it both ways round for the date column, I get errors.  If I keep it as yr/m/d, how the original data was formatted, I get dput() of :

```
structure(list(timestamp = c("2012/12/14 18:40:37", "2012/12/14 18:40:48", 
"2012/12/14 18:40:58", "2012/12/14 18:41:08"), LATITUDE = c(54.77769505, 
54.77765729, 54.77768751, 54.7777021), LONGITUDE = c(-1.56627049, 
-1.56639255, -1.56626555, -1.56662523), HEIGHT = c(" 173.911 M", 
" 161.742 M", " 146.905 M", " 138.016 M"), SPEED = c(" 0.465 km/h", 
" 0.728 km/h", " 4.574 km/h", " 17.335 km/h")), .Names = c("timestamp", 
"LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "HEIGHT", "SPEED"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

If I then use:

```
gps2$timestamp <- strptime(gps2$timestamp, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

... and try to view the dataframe in R Studio's workspace window, the R session aborts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to load character vectors as such and not factors using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (as shown below)

```
# make sure character columns are not converted to factors
df1 <- data.frame(a, D, Time, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then,

```
df1 <- within(df1, { timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(D, Time)), 
                               "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })
# convert timestamp here
df1$timestamp <- strptime(df1$timestamp, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Now, try subset this way:

```
# now subset
subset(df1, timestamp > strptime("14/12/2012 18:42:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))


#     a          D     Time           timestamp
# 10 10 2012/12/14 18:42:08 2012-12-14 18:42:08
# 11 11 2012/12/14 18:42:18 2012-12-14 18:42:18
# 12 12 2012/12/14 18:42:28 2012-12-14 18:42:28
# 13 13 2012/12/14 18:42:38 2012-12-14 18:42:38
# 14 14 2012/12/14 18:42:48 2012-12-14 18:42:48
# 15 15 2012/12/14 18:42:58 2012-12-14 18:42:58
# 16 16 2012/12/14 18:43:08 2012-12-14 18:43:08
# 17 17 2012/12/14 18:43:18 2012-12-14 18:43:18
# 18 18 2012/12/14 18:42:28 2012-12-14 18:42:28
# 19 19 2012/12/14 18:44:18 2012-12-14 18:44:18
# 20 20 2012/12/14 18:44:28 2012-12-14 18:44:28
# 21 21 2012/12/14 18:44:28 2012-12-14 18:44:28
```

**Edit:** Try this:

```
df1 <- within(df1, { timestamp=as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })
df1$timestamp <- strptime(df1$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Many thanks @Arun.  My original dataframe is imported as a csv file.  How to I convert my 'Time' column to factors when I import it to R?  I normally use gps <- read.csv(file="Example.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",").

Comment: `read.csv` also has `stringsAsFactors` parameter. you can just add `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks.  When I try to apply the code [df1$timestamp <- strptime(df1$timestamp, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")] to my own dataframe (imported with the stringsAsFactors=FALSE), I get a very random intergrated date column comprising strings of numbers for each row of data.  I obviously can't show this here, but no you have any suggestions?

Comment: After loading your `csv` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, you should use the command where you `format` it to `%d/%m/%Y...` first before applying `strptime`. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes.  Obviously I changed the dataframe and column names to my own, but everything else was the same.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, can't say much without looking at the data. If you can edit your post with the new data and your code I'd be glad to debug!

Comment: No worries, thanks @Arun.  I don't really know what my data is doing.  I'll try and get a workable subset up here but in the meantime I get the following error: Error in Date > strptime("18/12/2012 14:30:19", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.POSIXt") for ">"
2: In Date > strptime("18/12/2012 14:30:19", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length  Is this any help?

Comment: Many thanks @Arun.  I have used dput() to output my data.  If you could possibly have a look and advise me how I might overcome this problem, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Arun.. Many thanks for your help.  However, it's still not working I am afraid (see my editted question).

Comment: The first code in your second edit is NOT the same as the one I pasted in my edit at the bottom of the post.

Comment: The problem is that in your first example you have dates in the order "YYYY/MM/DD" where as the data you're working on (the one you pasted now) has the order DD/MM/YYYY. You'll have to settle on a format and use the POSIXct and strptime formats accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Arun, apologies for that oversight.  But even when I do (see edit above), my R session aborts.  I just don't understand what is wrong with my data (or my code).

Comment: @KT_1, I think this is a problem with the Rstudio... maybe? I don't get any error! Your code works fine for me (Edit 3)!! Maybe clear everything, start a new session (don't allow .RData to load) or maybe a fresh clean install?

Comment: Thanks @Arun.  I have tried reinstalling and the same problem occurs.  I have also tried another computer, and again the same. I emailed R Studio and they said it was the code.  I am on a work network, but I can't think why that would have an effect.  I have a mac at home, I will try that tonight.  Sorry for the extended comments, I feel I am just going around in circles.

Comment: I tried your Edit 3 and it works great! Maybe you'll have to reinstall R? Anyhoo good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Arun.  Have tried on my home laptop and alas no errors!! Just one question, my dates are originally in the format of 2012-12-14 18:40:3.  Should the dashes between the year and month (as opposed to the '/') make a difference in the code when I convert to timestamp etc.?

Comment: Yes, when you write the format of the date: `%Y = year, %m = month, %d = date, %H = hour, %M = minutes, %S = seconds`. All these should be mentioned in the same order as your date: In this case, for example, if you want to convert to POSIXct, then `as.POSIXct("2012-12-14 18:40:30", format="%Y-%m-$d %H:%M:%S")`. Note the `-` and the mentioning of what is where correctly.

Comment: Very intersting - thanks, that all works now @Arun.  Final question (I promise).  If I want to change the '-' to '/' and format the dates more UK style (12/12/2012) - at what stage should this be done?